# How do I map keys to assign a value in vim?

Tags: vim, keymapping

I am using highlighted search in vim. So when I search for a word, all occurrences of the word get highlighted. After I'm done, I want to remove the highlighting.
According to the [Vim Documentation](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/pattern.html#last-pattern), `:let @/=""` clears the last searched pattern and removes the highlighting.

So I am trying to map `Ctrl+/` to `:let @/=""`.

I've added the following line to my .vimrc

```
nnoremap <C-/> :let @/=""<CR>
```

But it doesn't work. `Ctrl+/` doesn't clear the search patter. On the other hand, if I manually type in `:let @/=""`, it works fine.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Why don't you use the built-in `:nohls` for this?

Comment: `<C-/>` isn't being interpreted by vim. Choosing a different mapping works.

Comment: @glts I didn't know about that. I'll use that instead. But the key binding still didn't work.

Comment: @FDinoff You're right. I bound `<C-m>` and it worked. So why doesn't vim interpret `<C-/>`?

Comment: The explanation is the same as the one given here http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/24261/how-do-i-send-c-that-is-control-slash-to-the-terminal

Answer (score 1):

I use this in my vimrc:

```
nnoremap <Esc> :noh<CR>
```

Mapping this to <kbd>Esc</kbd> seems natural to me.

Comment: I actually did: `nnoremap <C-m> :nohls<CR>` and it worked. I wonder why vim doesn't interpret `<C-/>`, though.

Answer (score 0):

Due to the way that the keyboard input is handled internally, this unfortunately isn't generally possible today, even in GVIM. Some key combinations, like <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + non-alphabetic cannot be mapped, and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + letter vs. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + letter cannot be distinguished. (Unless your terminal sends a distinct *termcap* code for it, which most don't.) In insert or command-line mode, try typing the key combination. If nothing happens / is inserted, you cannot use that key combination. This also applies to `<Tab>` / `<C-I>`, `<CR>` / `<C-M>` / `<Esc>` / `<C-[>` etc. (Only exception is `<BS>` / `<C-H>`.) This is a known pain point, and the subject of various discussions on vim_dev and the #vim IRC channel.

Some people (foremost Paul LeoNerd Evans) want to fix that (even for console Vim in terminals that support this), and have floated various proposals, cp. http://groups.google.com/group/vim_dev/browse_thread/thread/626e83fa4588b32a/bfbcb22f37a8a1f8

But as of today, no patches or volunteers have yet come forward, though many have expressed a desire to have this in a future Vim 8 major release.